# Load third-party non-CakePHP library

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to integrate a proprietary third-party library into my CakePHP app. All I could find in the manual is the [App Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html) section but it's basically a set of examples rather than a proper explanation so I'm trying to guess.

I got the impression that you should use the `App::uses()` alternative when possible and at first I thought I was lucky because this code:

```
App::build(
    array(
        'Vendor' => array(
            APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'base',
            APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'foo',
            APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'bar',
        )
    )
);
debug(App::objects('Vendor'));
```

... produces this output:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'Autoload',
    (int) 1 => 'ConstantsBase',
    (int) 2 => 'Foo',
    (int) 3 => 'Bar',
)
```

However, I can't do anything like this:

```
App::uses('Foo', 'Vendor');
new Foo();
```

... triggers:

```
Error: Class 'Foo' not found
```

How comes CakePHP does know about the library classes but won't load them?

Comment: Are you using composer in your project and does the vendor libs support composer as well?

Comment: I see `composer.json` files all around but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Are you familiar with other Package Managers like bower? Composer is pretty similar and is a common tool now in the php world. I would recommend you to use it because it comes with a standard autoloader and you can manage your dependencies through it as well. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer

Comment: @burzum I've used Node's npm and Composer is definitively in my todo list. But this particular library is not Composer-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, directory paths need to have a trailing slash:

```
// Incorrect
APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'base',

// Correct
APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'base' . DS,
```

It's just mandatory, though its omission doesn't seem to trigger any error message.

Comment: Why should it create an error as it does produce a valid path after all: `APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'base'` and `'foobar' . DS` become `APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Acme' . DS. 'API-1.0' . DS . 'basefoobar' . DS`.

Comment: @mark - I honestly can't figure out a use case for that. Never mind, I'll never forget trailing slashes again :)